# PHP: json_decode assoc array not displaying value

Tags: php, json

After a `json_decode` this is the `var_dump` of the assoc array:

```
array(1) { 
    [0]=> array(8) { 
        ["Username"]=> string(11) "test" 
        ["FirstName"]=> string(6) "Test1" 
        ["LastName"]=> string(5) "Test2" 
        ["Gender"]=> string(6) "Male" 
     }
}
```

if try to echo `$array["FirstName"]` it doesn't display anything, I've tried everything and nothing works.

Comment: try `$array[0]["FirstName"]`

Comment: Always format your code so that others can read and understand it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's because there is no such key as `FirstName` on the main array. However, there is one on the inner array.

```
echo $array[0]['FirstName'];
```

Note that if you had enabled `show_errors` and had suitable `error_reporting` set, you would have seen a Notice-level error informing you of the problem.

Comment: Thank you for all your help everyone, I'll be sure to do that next time.